# Bad request from solr by just changing the order in the filter query

Tags: solr

The following solr request works just fine:

```
&json.facet={domains:{type:terms,field:domains,domain:{excludeTags:DOMAIN}},specialties:{type:terms,field:specialties,domain:{excludeTags:SPECIALTY}}}
&fq={!tag=SPECIALTY}specialties:(1043 1023) AND {!tag=DOMAIN}domains:100
```

If I just change the order in the fq parameter, solr response with 400 Bad Request.

```
&json.facet={domains:{type:terms,field:domains,domain:{excludeTags:DOMAIN}},specialties:{type:terms,field:specialties,domain:{excludeTags:SPECIALTY}}}
&fq={!tag=DOMAIN}domains:100 AND {!tag=SPECIALTY}specialties:(1043 1023)
```

I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong or it if could be a problem in solr.

I'm using solr 7.2.1 and I'm following thes tutorial from Yonik:
http://yonik.com/multi-select-faceting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very weird. A colleague found that by adding an space between the tag and the field the query works as expected in any order. Also, adding the plus sign force to match all conditions. Here is the working query, just adding space and plus sign in fq parameter:

```
&json.facet={domains:{type:terms,field:domains,domain:{excludeTags:DOMAIN}},specialties:{type:terms,field:specialties,domain:{excludeTags:SPECIALTY}}}
&fq={!tag=DOMAIN} +domains:100 AND {!tag=SPECIALTY} +specialties:(1043 1023)
```

Use this with caution. This might be a hack. The documentation is not clear about this.

Answer (score 2):

A localparam (i.e. the thing between `{}`) *has* to be the first thing in a parameter. The second localparam you've added in the middle of your filterquery isn't being used as you expect it to, but when you move it to the front, it's suddenly being parsed.

You should split the two parts into separate `fq`s:

```
&fq={!tag=DOMAIN}domains:100
&fq={!tag=SPECIALTY}specialties:(1043 1023)
```

If you still get a Bad Request 400 - check the actual server log in your Solr instance - it'll show you what part it's barfing about (misspelling, etc.).

Comment: This query works, but the result is not the expected one.

Comment: What is the difference to the expected result?